# Где найти всю информацию о CMS?

Tags: веб-программирование, cms

Заинтересовался таким вопрос, вот если взять какой-то сайт который на какой-либо CMS, тот же WordPress и посмотреть информацию на [2ip.ru](https://2ip.ru) или [pr-cy.ru](https://pr-cy.ru), то мы увидим, что сайт на WordPress. Откуда они достают эту информацию? Я в курсе про мета тег `generator` но в нем хранится только название, а где тогда логотип CMS лежит? Я не думаю, что они ищут эту CMS в гугле и получают логотип. Давайте тогда отойдем от `generator` и они все равно находят информацию на чем сделан сайте. Так куда рыть? Давайте возьмем на пример WordPress, где вся информация его лежит?

Comment: **логотип CMS** может хранится у вас в коде) тег generator можно убрать.. можно собрать информацию о директориях например, и проверять на существование) например /wp-admin там всякие

Comment: а как они тогда этот логотип находят?

Comment: Ну вот представим я захотел написать свою CMS, куда мне кидать информацию и логотип, чтобы показывалось на 2ip?

Comment: @KILLER да при чем там логотип вообще)) CMS не по логотипу отпределяют. Ну а так, наверное чтобы Вашу CMS определяло на таких сервисах, она должна обрести определенную популярность.

Comment: Каждый движок имеет свою уникальную структуру, которые многие не скрывают, например в WordPress все начинается на `wp-` (`wp-admin`, `wp-includes`, `wp-content`, и так далее), у многих даже стили дефолтные остаются, которые также начинаются на `wp-` (`wp-block`, `wp--preset` и др.). Некоторые движки даже Cookie свои имеют (например ASP.NET). Вот собрав эту информацию в одно целое, можно написать тест, который зайдет на сайт и проанализирует его, сверит со своей базой и выдаст результат.